# movzx/movsx behavior on x64

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64

Based on the documentation of movzx,if I write code like, movzx eax,bx. I should only assume that upper 24 bits of eax will be zero out. However after reading some articles, I find that CPU actually gonna zero out the whole 64 bits register.In this case the rax's upper 56 bits will be zeros. I am just wondering if this behavior should be relied on since it is really helpful in my case.

Comment: In 64-bit mode - If the destination register of an instruction is a 32-bit register the CPU automatically zero extends the value across the upper 32-bits of the 64-bit register. So yes, `movzx eax,bx` would zero extend BX int EAX and since EAX is a 32-bit register  the processor will implicitly zero extend that through the upper 32-bit of _RAX_ as well.

Comment: In the case of `movsx eax,bx` it would sign extend _BX_ through _EAX_ and then the processor will automatically set the upper 32-bits of _RAX_ to 0.

Comment: *"I should only assume that upper 24 bits of eax"* - you mean upper 16 bits? (`bx` is 16 bits, `eax` is 32 bits, 32-16=16).